# Can't connect to database?

Tags: mongodb, npm, mongoose

after running the following command, I got err, could you help me check this?  Thank you
The database Im using is MongoDB,bot sure if it's the version.

$  node database-mongodb/seed.js

```
> problem-starter@1.0.0 db:setup /Users/Wilson/Desktop/test/***/blogmodo
> node database-mongodb/seed.js
(node:4912) DeprecationWarning: `open()` is deprecated in mongoose >= 4.11.0, use `openUri()` instead, or set the `useMongoClient` option if using `connect()` or `createConnection()`. See http://mongoosejs.com/docs/4.x/docs/connections.html#use-mongo-client

events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (/Users/Wilson/Desktop/test/***/blogmodo/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:336:35)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at Connection.<anonymous> (/Users/Wilson/Desktop/test/***/blogmodo/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:280:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:277:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/Wilson/Desktop/test/***/blogmodo/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:189:49)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:277:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:50:3)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Immediate.<anonymous> (/Users/Wilson/Desktop/test/***/blogmodo/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:325:19)
    at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
    at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! problem-starter@1.0.0 db:setup: `node database-mongodb/seed.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the problem-starter@1.0.0 db:setup script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/Wilson/.npm/_logs/2020-04-25-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is already a server running on the port which your server should be running, you can try to restart your pc

you can also a this line after your mongoose.connect("connection string")

useMongoClient: true,

Comment: Just fixed this morning, the reason is I did't start the db at beginning. Thank you.